# Only allow specific emails to register to user role drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, acl

I am trying to find out how to allow only .ac.uk emails register to a spcific user role in drupal 7

Every where i have looked gives options with access control in earlier drupal versions but not DR7

Any hack/ module suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is no longer in core, however there are at least three ways of doing it now in drupal 7 (in order of ease).

1. Drop in the contrib [User Restrictions module](http://drupal.org/project/user_restrictions).
2. Use the Rules module (I can't seem to find a good rule for filtering this, but it's not super hard to figure out).
3. Write your own simple module that implements hook_user_presave.

Comment: couldn't find a good rule that worked or a tutorial to guide so went with option 1 seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you went down the custom module route, you could do this by using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) on the registration form. Add your own validation function that would deny emails that are not .ac.uk